# Is it wrong to define the integral just as a summation of hyperreal numbers?

Tags: integration, summation

Can we just say that the only difference between these two notations: $\sum$ and $\int$ is that the first is a summation for real numbers and the second one for hyperreals?

Comment: I've heard it described that the first is a countable summation, and the second is an uncountable summation.

Comment: In the spirit of the comment by @Arthur, if we wanted to describe integral like that, we would need to somehow make our sum "uncountable", because countable set of values of the function doesn't yet determine the value of integral